# Регулярные выражения в qt

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, qt, qt5

Суть проблемы: Написал я регулярное выражение, которое ищет '{' и оглядывается назад, чтобы посмотреть, нет ли там признака коментариев, и когда оно находит данный символ, которому не предшествует коментарий, оно заменяет его на другую последовательность символов. Но увы, оно не работает уже который час. Будьте добры, друзья, подскажите, где ошибся:

```
    while (start >= 0 && end >=0) {
        start = text.indexOf("\n", start);
        end  = text.indexOf(QRegExp("^.*[{](?!=[//]|[/*]|[*]))"),start);
        end2  = text.indexOf(QRegExp("^.*[}](?!=[//]|[/*]|[*]))"), start);
        if (end < end2) {
            text.replace(end,"\n{\n");
        }
        else  text.replace(end2,"\n}\n");
        ++start;
    }
```

допустим есть текст, вида:

```
//dfsdkfj ksjdfksjdf {  <- этот символ должен быть пропущен
public SystemBlock()
{  <- этот должен быть найден
    this.producer = "none";
    this.motherBoard = "none";
    this.processor = "none";
    this.ram = "none";
    this.gpu = "none";
    this.price = 0;
    this.eventSupport = null;
}
```

Comment: Приведите минимальный фрагмент, на котором не срабатывает.

Comment: @ixSci  версия 5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не думаю, что у Вас получится сделать это с регулярными выражениями, т.к. PCRE не поддерживает negative lookbehind произвольного размера, а как по другому тут сделать не совсем понятно. С другой стороны, Ваша задача решается элементарно другим способом: Вы разделяете текст на строки и в каждой строке ищете `{`, если находите, то ищете в этой строке `//`(или другой символ комментариев): если есть, значит пропускаете, если нет — заменяете.

Comment: у меня была идея разделить на строки, но потом решил поиграть с регулярными выражениями. Видимо да, придется либо резать на строки, либо юзать \n и  indexOf || lastIndexOf.

Во всяком случае, спасибо за обратную связь.)

Comment: @Max, если Вы согласны с ответом, отметьте его, пожалуйста, как принятый. Часто, самый простой код, основанный на тех же `indexOf()` и `lastIndexOf()`, оказывается и наиболее эффективным. В Qt, также, не зря имеются классы, типа `QStringMatcher` и `QByteArrayMatcher`, позволяющие в отдельных случаях без всяких регулярок существенно повысить эффективность поиска символов.